# Can XAML tag names be bound?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a simple Question.. Is it possible to use binding like this:

```
<my:{Binding Path=Foo} />
```

The reason why I want to do this is I need the `foo` to change by using conditional compilation, for Example:

```
#if BAR
   var foo = "FooBar"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know having dynamic changes to the XAML markup itself is not possible in WPF.
If you do need to have something like this I would suggest that you use one of your possible classes in XAML to keep design support and to have a valid XAML file and then write a little tool that runs through all your xaml files before compilation and exchanges `Foo` with `Bar` if a certain condition is met. Obviously you would need to make sure that `Foo` and `Bar` are interchangeable too.

Effectively your XAML would look like this

```
<my:Foo .../>
```

and your tool would check a condition and then exchange `Foo` with `Bar` in all your xaml files.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to a different property based on a pre-processor directive? That doesn't sound easy to do to me.  Wouldn't it be better to have the the Xaml use the same property but for the property to use a different body/field:

```
public string MyDebugFoo { get; set; }
public string MyOtherFoo { get; set; }

public string Foo {
#if DEBUG
  get { return MyDebugFoo; } }
  set { MyDebugFoo = value; } }        
#else
  get { return MyOtherFoo; } }
  set { MyOtherFoo = value; } }
#endif 
}
```